# How to pass variable with a master layout in Codeiginiter

Tags: codeigniter

My master layout here's below and working fine. I just want little bit more passing a default variable with this master layout that I can get in every pages.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public $layout;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->layout='layout/master';
}
```

}

I need to pass variable like below:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $data['msg'] = $this->session->flashdata('usermsg');
    $this->layout=('layout/master',$data);
}
```

How do I get this.

Comment: Have provide with a solution. Share me if you face any hindrance in development. @Mir Abzal Ali

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading up the data dynamically from the controller with the help of `$this->layout` you can send the data like this.

**Method 1:**

If you are using the general method to load the data to the view you can use this method.

```
$this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
```

This will load the profile_view page along with the `$data` as you passs into it with the help of `array()`

**Method 2:**

If you have created a master Layout and you are passing the data from the controller to the Master Layout you need to do like this.

```
<?php
public function master_layout () {
$this->template['header'] = $this->load->view('include/header', $this->Front_End_data, true);
$this->template['navigation'] = $this->load->view('include/navigation', $this->Front_End_data, true);
$this->template['center'] = $this->load->view($this->middle, $this->Front_End_data, true);
$this->template['footer'] = $this->load->view('include/footer', $this->Front_End_data, true);
$this->load->view('include/index', $this->template);
?>
```

In this code the below line alone will be loaded dynamically based on the page which you call in the master Layout.

```
$this->template['center'] = $this->load->view($this->middle, $this->Front_End_data, true);
```

In order to pass the data to this `center` layout you can use the funciton like this.

```
$data['msg'] = 'Success';
$this->template['center'] = $this->load->view ($this->middle = 'pages/view_oage',$data, true);
$this->master_layout();
```

And in the page you can get the data to be printed using the foreach loop as follows.

```
foreach($msg as $value)
{
echo $value;
}
```